# Proper python way to clear a bytearray

Tags: python, arrays

I miss memset.  I have a frame buffer in a class, it has data in it from some other operations, and now I want to clear everything in that frame buffer to 0x00 or 0xFF.  I didn't see a clear method in the docs, there's a zfill method that might work.  I thought about just calling the init method of the byte array again but wondered if that might cause me some memory trouble down the road.

I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

Python *is not C*, here you don't need to worry about memory <strike>at all</strike> much. You just simply do:

```
a = bytearray("abcd") # initialized it with real data

a = bytearray(5) # just a byte array of size 5 filled with zeros
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. Why would you choose a high-level language (Python) to use it like a low-level one (C)?

Comment: Well, this would work in some cases. But there are bytearray-like objects such as `mmap` where you'd actually sometimes want to zero the contents.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, bytearray-like is not the same as `bytearray`, right?

Comment: Basically this is almost always the wrong answer.  bytearray's are rarely used ... and are when they are it is precisely because memory management is critical.

Comment: High speed data parsing of binary data (from a serial port for example) ends up potentially requiring fast setting and clearing of data within a fixed memory size and position internal buffer (the RAM fills up fast using a 'high level' approach), and once you hit virtual memory the performance suffers a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: ba = bytearray(range(100))

In [2]: ba
Out[2]: bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abc')

In [3]: ba[:] = b'\x00' * len(ba)

In [4]: ba
Out[4]: bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do high-performance manipulations on a framebuffer, consider using NumPy. You can represent your framebuffer as a NumPy array of `uint8`s:

```
import numpy as np
fb = np.zeros((480, 640), dtype=np.uint8) # a 640x480 monochrome framebuffer
```

and then clear the framebuffer very simply:

```
fb[:] = 0 # or fb[:] = 0xff
```

The other big advantage is that you get a fast, 2D array - you can do things like `fb[80:120, 40:60]` to get a rectangular region cheaply, and you can implement draw operations like blitting with very little code. Plus, with `np.tobytes` you can still obtain a bytes representation.